# Lenovo g500 on ubuntu, battery won't charge over 59%

Tags: battery

When I had windows I used lenovo energy managment and set the battery to charge up to 60% only as it recommended it to me. Yesterday I switched to Ubuntu and now I have this problem. It would be great if I could fix this without installing windows again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your BIOS and change it there.
2. upgrade your BIOS
3. If the BIOS doesn't allow you to upgrade, do it the hard way:

   - make print screens (if you have a parallel printer) or write down your settings on a piece of paper,
   - reset the BIOS to default factory settings,
   - reboot. Shut down the power while in the BIOS splash
   - press the power button again to start
   - Set the BIOS settings you need from your piece of paper
   - continue booting normally

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)